# How to use adobes Live Cycle ES2 Java Api with PHP to convert XDP to PDF

Tags: php, livecycle, xdp-pdf

I want to use Adobe's Live Cycle ES2 java api to through PHP to convert XDP files to PDF

Following are the links from adobes help pages

```
1. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=000281.html
2. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/index.htm?content=000995.html
```

**Question:** These question may look silly or basic but i am not getting any answer on internet so posting here

```
1. Is this solution free or paid? 
2. From where I can get/purchase the API?
```

Please advice

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The current version of LiveCycle is ES3 and is available for purchase from Adobe.  You can contact sales@twintechs.com or contact Adobe directly at 888-649-2990.  Converting XDP's to PDF's is only the tip of the iceberg of what LiveCycle offers.

Comment: Just be aware that LC doesn't accept many things like old-style compressed jpegs, secured or PDF-A. I know they have good reasons but I had to create a whole workflow system tracking the errors and fixing the files and resubmitting. Unless there is an easier way?